# Mysql alterar automaticamente dados

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, trigger

Boa tarde, queria implementar um sistema que fizesse com que a minha base dados automaticamente, alterasse o valor de um dos campos de um elemento quando o campo data expiração fosse superior a data actual do sistema. Já tentei implementar ataraves de evento, mas queria atraves de trigger, podem-me ajudar?
Obrigado

Comment: seria bom adicionar o que você já fez na sua pergunta pois será mais fácil formular uma resposta adequada

Answer (score 1):

Suponhamos que temos um banco de dados com uma tabela que armazena os dados dos empregados da empresa. Se por ventura alguém fizer uma modificação nessa tabela, e alterar especificamente o sobrenome de um  funcionário, iremos poder auditar isso através de outra tabela chamada empregados_auditoria. Quem irá preencher a tabela empregados_auditoria é a nossa trigger de exemplo que será executada antes de qualquer UPDATE na tabela empregados.

== Criando as tabelas que serão usadas nesse exemplo ==

**tabela de empregados**

```
CREATE TABLE `empregados` (
      `id_empregado` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `sobrenome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `nome` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
      `cargo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY  (`id_empregado`)
)
```

**tabela empregados_auditoria**

```
CREATE TABLE empregados_auditoria ( 
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    id_empregado int(11) NOT NULL, 
    sobrenome varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    modificadoem datetime DEFAULT NULL, 
    acao varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id) 
)
```

== Criando nossa Trigger de exemplo ==

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER antesDeUpdate_empregados 
BEFORE UPDATE ON empregados
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
INSERT INTO empregados_auditoria
SET acao = 'update',
id_empregado = OLD.id_empregado,
sobrenome = OLD.sobrenome,
modificadoem = NOW(); END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

== Testando o funcionamento da nossa Trigger de exemplo ==

Como nossa trigger é chamada somente quando é feito um UPDATE na tabela empregados, e essa tabela está vazia no momento, precisamos incluir pelo menos um registro nela:

```
INSERT INTO `empregados` (`id_empregado`, `sobrenome`, `nome`, `email`, `cargo`) VALUES ('1', 'Silva', 'Ciclano', 'ciclano@teste.com', 'Programador');
```

Agora precisamos executar um UPDATE que modifique o sobrenome de um empregado para que a trigger antesDeUpdate_empregados seja executada:

```
UPDATE empregados SET sobrenome = 'Santana' WHERE id_empregado = 1;
```

Se executarmos um SELECT na tabela empregados poderemos ver o nome do empregado que cadastramos e depois alteramos:

```
SELECT * FROM empregados;
```

Para termos certeza de que a trigger foi executada com sucesso basta fazermos uma consulta na tabela empregados_auditoria e veremos que a trigger se encarregou de inserir um registro nessa tabela automaticamente:

```
SELECT * FROM empregados_auditoria;
```

Já da para ter uma ideia assim.

Comment: sim, percebi, o sistema, porem nao consigo aplicar a minha situação. Tenho uma tabela de anúncios, cada anuncio tem entre outros dados, uma data de expiração e um estado. Eu queria uma forma automática de alterar o estado quando o anuncio expirasse

Answer (score 0):

Você tem certeza de que você quer uma trigger pra isso? Eu acho que é mais seguro você fazer algo do tipo

```
CREATE TABLE anuncios (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    data_expiracao DATETIME NOT NULL,
    -- outros campos…
    -- (mas não o campo de “estado” do anúncio)
);

CREATE VIEW anuncios_estado AS
SELECT
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN data_expiracao < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP THEN 'expirado'
        -- outros casos vão aqui
    END AS estado
FROM anuncios;
     -- INNER JOIN outras tabelas auxiliares
```

Naturalmente você colocaria aí na view `anuncios_estado` a lógica pra decidir, por exemplo, se um anúncio está ativo (procurando, por exemplo, numa outra tabela se o pagamento relativo ao anúncio foi feito, ou algo do gênero). Aí na hora de consultar você teria que fazer algo tipo

```
FROM anuncios INNER JOIN anuncios_estado USING (id)
```

pra puxar o campo de estado.

A vantagem de fazer desse jeito é que você não precisa pensar em todos os casos em que os dados que você vai consultar podem ser alterados — no dia que você criar um sistema de reembolso de anúncios, esse sistema vai automaticamente matar os anúncios na hora que o pagamento for estornado, sem o risco se você ter um anúncio num estado inconsistente; a *des*vantagem é que a consulta fica mais cara, mas 1) isso pode ser mitigado com o uso adequado de índices; 2) você ainda não sabe se isso de fato vai ser um gargalo; 3) o seu cliente ainda não sabe de fato o que determina o estado do anúncio, e gerar o estado dinamicamente te dá mais flexibilidade pra mudar.

No dia que você estiver apanhando da performance, você pode simplesmente fazer

```
CREATE TABLE anuncios_estado_precomputado (…)
```

E aí todo dia, ou de hora em hora, você bota um script pra rodar que faz

```
BEGIN;
DELETE FROM anuncios_estado_precomputado;
INSERT INTO anuncios_estado_precomputado
SELECT FROM anuncios_estado;
COMMIT;
```

(ou algo do tipo fazer um join da versão precomputada com a view, pra achar as linhas diferentes e atualizar só elas, se isso calhar de ser mais rápido)

Você pode, nesse dia, implementar também um conjunto de triggers pra atualizar anuncios_estado_precomputado sem precisar esperar esse job rodar, mas no momento em que `estado` for uma coluna explícita do seu modelo, você vai precisar da view — mesmo que você resolva fazer tudo com triggers, um dia você ou um usuário *vão* errar, e você *vai* precisar auditar quais anúncios não estão no estado que eles deveriam estar.

---

Ou, o argumento mais pragmático pra fazer com a view: SGBDs não são `cron`; eles não geram eventos (e portanto não podem disparar triggers) só pela passagem do tempo. Pra fazer isso que você quer, você teria que ter um cronjob emitindo os UPDATEs apropriados rodando e.g. de minuto em minuto, ou na frequência que o seu SGBD aguentaria processar essas expirações; a view não sofre dessas limitações e sempre retorna o status atualizado em tempo real.